# Can't edit or save CiviCase types

Tags: wordpress, civicase

I have a fresh install of CiviCRM v5.4.0 running on Wordpress. I wanted to modify the default CiviCase types, but the 'Save' button or the 'more' buttons are inactive, i.e. nothing happens when I click on them. Is this a known issue?

P.S. I'm running shoreditch theme 0.1-alpha22, but I have this issue regardless if I use the theme or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this is a core bug because of recent change. You can find temporary solution at [CiviCRM 5.4, Unable to create case type (angular validation error)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/civicrm-5-4-unable-to-create-case-type-angular-validation-error)

HTH

Pradeep